# How do you store recurring time periods on a database? Like "from the first of january to the last day of may"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, datetime, time

I have to store recurring date periods, similar to the one in the title, and I have no idea if there is an optimal day to do this. The first solution I came up with was to have day and month fields for start and end dates, but this solution doesnt sound very right to me.

I am using Ruby on Rails with SQL.

Answer (score 7):

To store recurring dates of arbitrary complexity, you want to look into temporal expressions.

Some gems available are: [runt](http://runt.rubyforge.org/), [TExp](http://texp.rubyforge.org/) or [icecube](https://github.com/seejohnrun/ice_cube)

I've used both runt and icecube, as well as storing recurring dates (weekly schedules) in serialized ruby objects.  The gems are the most flexible, if a little hard to use when your use case is simple.

Also if you need to parse textual expersions, look at [Chronic](http://chronic.rubyforge.org/)

Comment: This looks really interesting, I had never heard of temporal expressions before, thanks!

Comment: Runt is beautiful and can be serialised to the db too. Sad that it has not received more exposure and that it's not actively being maintained.

Answer (score 1):

In ruby, you could probably express this nicely (for a particular year) with a Range:

```
(Time.utc(2012, 1, 1)..Time.utc(2012, 5, 1).end_of_month)
```

But storing this in a database...can only think of doing what you said (columns for start/end day and month), and then adding wrapper methods on the model similar to this:

```
def current_start
  Time.utc(current_year, start_month, start_day)
end

...

def current_range
  (current_start..current_end)
end
```

Comment: This is the solution I had until this point, but it's good to hear it is not as bad as I felt, thanks

Comment: Thanks, but I actually voted for the temporal libraries answer - never heard of those before, but would use something around serializing that now.

Comment: I liked them the most as a solution, but I've taken a look at them and so far I havent found the way to express  what I need with them...

Answer (score 0):

I would just use two dates... afaik that maps nicely to ruby Date objects anyway, with which you can do the usual arithmetic.

Comment: But if I used dates I would have to specify the year, and I want this periods to be recurring for every year.

Comment: If the time periods are to be used repeatedly, i.e. with different years, storing a date would be awkward, as they contain a (fixed) year.